# Do we have "blades of hay" like "blades of grass"?

Tags: single-word-requests, plants

Grass comes in blades - the elongated foils, or leaves, growing out of the ground. Now, if we cut our grass and dry it, we've got hay. Obviously (?) there aren't "leaves of hay"; but what do we call the individual pieces of hay, which used to be blades/leaves of grass? Are they "blades of hay"? Something else?

**Edit:** I just can't decide between two quite reasonable and attractive options; I don't feel it's for me to choose one of these over the other, really...

Comment: I've mostly heard them referred to as ***bits*** of hay. I can't find a definition for the phrase, though.

Comment: "Stalk of hay" and "blades of grass"

Comment: A "blade" of grass is just the grass _leaf_. Whereas "hay" consists of a mixture of leaves, seeds and stalks/stems.

Answer (score 12):

One possibility is a *stalk* of hay, or *haystalk*:

> **[stalk](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stalk)** noun [ C ]
>   ​
>   the main stem of a plant, or the narrow stem that joins leaves, flowers, or fruit to the main stem of a plant:
>
> She trimmed the stalks of the tulips before putting them in a vase.

Cambridge Dictionary

> **[Haystalk](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Haystalk)**
>
> Also found in: Thesaurus, Medical, Encyclopedia, Wikipedia.
>   Related to Haystalk: hayrick, haystack, making hay
>
> n. A stalk of hay.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: But can hay be made up of stalks when grass doesn't have stalks?

Comment: @einpoklum How wouldn't grass have stalks? The entire plant is a stalk.

Comment: @einpoklum Hay consists of both the stalks and leaves of grass (and possibly even the seed-heads).

Comment: Hay and grass are not quite the same. To get a lawn of grass, we cut plants very short and evenly. If we did not, the grass stalks would show. Rye is a common ingredient in the blend of lawn grass, and you can picture rye stalks. Except that there is never a stalk to be seen when lawns are mowed.

Comment: @Yosef Meadow grass is normally allowed to grow to full height before it is mown for hay.

Comment: @Mick - Yes, and then the stalks would really show.

Comment: @Mick: Ok then, thanks for the horticultural lesson :-)

Comment: @einpoklum Next week: how to grow tomatoes. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

I think it is called a  ***hay [straw](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/straw)***:

> - a single dry or ripened stalk, esp of a grass.

(Dictionary.com)

From [Amanche](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0ZnAAAAMAAJ&q=%22a%20hay%20straw%22&dq=%22a%20hay%20straw%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhtI30wOjSAhWDCSwKHVjyAVkQ6AEILzAF)The Story of Japanese Internment in Colorado During World War II

> - A Mercedian was shown in a "hick" costume, complete with a ragged straw hat on his head ***and a hay straw in his mouth***, and remarking,
> - The minute she was out, she went to find Sweet Daddy. He leaned nonchalantly on a bale of hay, ***picking his teeth with a hay straw***. He refused to meet her eyes.

Comment: Ok, straw sounds good. If others upvote you and there are no alternative suggestions I'll take your word for it and accept :-)

Comment: Note that *straw* and *hay* are [not the same thing](http://www.usaforage.org/products/straw-vs-hay/), so more agriculturally literate audiences might not embrace this usage.

Comment: @choster - of course they are not, but "hay straw" defines a blade of  dried grass, not straw per se.

Comment: @choster Whether or not straw (mass noun) is the same as hay (mass noun), **a** straw (count noun) is entirely different from both. A straw is the ‘basic unit’ of anything that has the right basic shape, including both hay and straw; so you can have a straw of hay/hay straw, or even a straw of straw/straw straw. Most Germanic languages have different words for the blade-like structure and the dried material, and the cognate for _straw_ generally refers to the former, not the latter.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I didn't say the answer was wrong. Rather, I said to be judicious in its use because the word is commonly used in a way others may consider a misuse. For a different example, I wouldn't advise someone say they are flying from New York to London *direct* in a crowd of travel agents, even though flying direct is a separate concept from a *direct flight*, which is commonly used to mean a *nonstop flight*.

Comment: @einpoklum I really can't imagine ever using a word other than 'straw' and would use it either as "straws of hay" or "hay straws", but not as "straw" on it's own.

Comment: @Keith: Would you use "haystraw", without a space? Also, would you really not imagine saying "haystalk" ?

Comment: @einpoklum I would, and it would probably give me a very good idea of what's being described. I really can't imagine anyone ever using stalk unless they're talking about the very bottom, fresh growth of the plant. I grew up in the countryside, on a farm for several years, so I came across hay more than your average person. I'm not saying that qualifies me but I feel like I would have heard someone say 'haystalk' if it was at all common.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "Pieces of hay".

**[piece](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/piece):**

> - a separate or limited portion or quantity of something:
>     a piece of land; a piece of chocolate.

(dictionary.com)

**straw** and **stalk** both refer to the stem of the grass - while hay includes the leaves and seeds (as well as a proportion of stem) as evidenced by the following quote from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hay):

> It is the leaf and seed material in the hay that determines its quality.

**wisp** and **bit** are defined as:

> a handful or small bundle of straw, hay, or the like.

and:

> a small piece or quantity of anything: a bit of string.

respectively. (dictionary.com)

Thus they could be mistaken to mean a small quantity rather than an individual blade (although that could potentially also be the case for piece, so it is a judgment call).

Comment: Hello. I thought of a *wisp* of hay, too. (Note the spelling https://www.wordnik.com/words/wisp)